# How to prove that the following set in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is locally compact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Consider the set $X$ defined as: $$X=S^{1}\cup ((0,2)\times\{0\})\subset\mathbb{R}^{2}$$
Where $S^{1}$ is the circle with center at the origin and radius $1$.

It is clear that $S^{1}$ is a compact set, so it is automatically locally compact but the set ((0,2) x {0}) is neither open nor closed in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, so I cannot say that it is compact. So I wanted to analyze the whole set and not in parts, so how can I prove that for every point $x\in X$ there exists a compact neighborhood or maybe there is another way to prove that $X$ is locally compact?

Comment: It is straightforward to check that every point in $X$ has a neighbourhood that is contained in a compact subset of $X$. (There are various definitions of locally compact, but I suspect they amount to much the same in the above case.)

Comment: I think what may help you is to ask a simpler question: why is $(0,2)$ locally compact? If you can answer this, why does it immediately tell you e.g. that $((0,2)\times\{0\})\cup(\{1\}\times [0,1])$ is locally compact? If you can answer these questions, you should be able to see immediately why your $X$ is locally compact, via the same reasoning.

Comment: To show that $(0,2)\subset\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology is locally compact, I can think of 2 ways. The first and most sophisticated is that since $(0,2)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is locally compact and Hausdorff then $(0,2)$ is locally compact. The other way would be because $[0+\varepsilon,2-\varepsilon]\subset (0,2)$, with $0<\varepsilon<2$, is a compact that contains all the points of $(0,2)$. Thus $(0,2)$ is locally compact.  I am right?

Comment: Well, the point $(1,0)$ needs a little more attention. Same idea, but since this is a proof.

Comment: @copper.hat The set $[\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}]\times \{0\}$ is a compact of $ X $ that contains the point $(0,1)$. It's right?

Comment: Well, a neighbourhood of $(1,0)$ contains points of $S^1$ as well, that was the point of my comment.

Comment: $[\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}]\times \{0\}$ is not a neighborhood of $(1,0)$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice little quality of life improvement that can make it convenient to verify a subspace is locally compact:

As a general matter, a subspace of a locally compact Hausdorff space is itself locally compact if and only if it is locally closed, i.e., it is the intersection of a closed and open subspace  (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3601768/1210477) for a proof in the direction that we need, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/326165/1210477) for a proof in the other direction.)

We have $X=U\cap C$, where

$$C=S^{1}\cup ([0,2]\times\{0\})\subset\mathbb{R}^{2}$$
is closed,
and $$U =\mathbb R^2\backslash \left(\{0,2\}\times \{0\}\right)$$
is open,
hence $X$ is locally closed, and therefore locally compact.